# Writing a Formula to List all Entries which Match to Transaction Amount

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a formula to list the 5 GL Line Items highlighted in yellow in the blue cell highlighted in yellow based on the fact that they all share the same 'Trans Ref Debit Total'. I can get the count of matches with a countif formula, but I basically want to concatenate the GL entries into a string as such:

"GL10_171094 GL10_171096 GL10_171098 GL10_171100 GL10_171102"

Any suggestiuons?

[image: Spreadsheet]

Comment: You will need Office 365, vba or a helper column.  Office 365 has the TEXTJOIN() function, while others will require the use of a helper column and then VLOOKUP.

Comment: How would I implement a helper column to assist with a vlookup? If I use a vlookup or match formula, it will just provide the first entry, i.e., GL10_171094.

Comment: Hence the need of a helper column that concatenates the values one by one as it finds similar entries.  There are many examples on the web on how to do this.

Comment: Do you need a single line answer or in all five cells? I think single line Concatenate in One Cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this simply made UDF.

*To store it Right Click the Sheet Tab, Click View Code, then insert this Code as Module.*

```
Function ConcatenateIf(CriteriaRange As range, Condition As Variant, ConcatenateRange As range, Optional Separator As String = ",") As Variant

Dim xResult As String
On Error Resume Next

If CriteriaRange.count <> ConcatenateRange.count Then
    ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    Exit Function
End If

For I = 1 To CriteriaRange.count
    If CriteriaRange.Cells(I).Value = Condition Then
        xResult = xResult & Separator & ConcatenateRange.Cells(I).Value
    End If
Next I

If xResult <> "" Then
    xResult = VBA.Mid(xResult, VBA.Len(Separator) + 1)
End If

  ConcatenateIf = xResult

  Exit Function

End Function
```

**NB:** Finally write this Formula in Cell B2.

```
  =ConcatenateIf(C2:C16,C2,A2:A16)
```

Answer (score 0):

You write this Formula in Blue Column. I'm assuming is column B.

So Formula in B2

```
=IF(C2<>C1,CONCATENATE(A2,", ",B2,),"")
```

Drag it till last Row. With your data you get Combined value in every last row of Code Set.

*First you get in Row 6 then 7 to 9 then in 14th Row.*

Hope this help you.